# Cannot echo variables after form submittiom

Tags: php

So I am submitting a form to the same page. I have used the following code to check whether the form was submitted, and to avoid 'undefined variables' errors during the first page reload.

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            // Get search variables
            $pName = $_POST['pname'];
            $pLocation = $_POST['plocation'];
            $pPrice = $_POST['pprice'];
        
            if (isset($_POST['ptype'])){
                $pType = $_POST['ptype'];
            }
        
            echo "pType";
        }
```

However, I cannot echo the php variables onto the page. I am guessing this is because the form is refreshed when it is sent by post, so the variables are lost.

How can I fix this problem?

This is the html form

```
<form method="post" action="../html/searchpage.php">
            <div id="searchborder">
                <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="         Property name">
                <input type="text" id="plocation" name="plocation" placeholder="        Property location">
                <input type="number" id="pprice" name="pprice" placeholder="          Property price">
            
                <div id="ptypeholder">
                <div id="ptypebox">
                    <select name="ptype">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Post type</option>
                        <option value="buy">Buy</option>
                        <option value="rent">Rent</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit"><img src="../images/search.png"></button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

I am trying to display 'property posts' into html cards from a database using php in this page. The form is the search bar for the property posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you did this ( echo "pType" )? in php you echo with the $ sign, so you do echo $pType!

Comment: When forms are submitted, it always refreshes the page (excluding things like Ajax), it doesn't lose the variables in this step because that step is actually required to SEND the variables. It seems like your problem is that it should be `echo $pType` instead of `echo 'pType'`.

Comment: I had actually put it as '$ptype' in the code. So that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think $_POST['submit'] is being set because the button needs a name ie

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

also you have a few other syntax errors, structure, may be this will help :-

```
<form method="post" action="searchpage.php">           
<input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Property name">
<input type="text" id="plocation" name="plocation" placeholder="Property location">
<input type="number" id="pprice" name="pprice" placeholder="Property price">                
<select name="ptype">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Post type</option>
    <option value="buy">Buy</option>
    <option value="rent">Rent</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

and you don't HAVE to assign the post values to $vars you can use them directly -

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get variables
    //$pName = $_POST['pname'];
    //$pLocation = $_POST['plocation'];
    //$pPrice = $_POST['pprice'];
    echo $_POST['ptype'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['pname'].'<br>';
    echo $_POST['plocation'].'<br>';    
    echo $_POST['pprice'].'<br>';                    
}
?>
```

Needs more work to make it check all posts are set or validation but works as a basic starting point

Also in original you posted `echo "pType";` will only echo the text pType not the value